# $P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{3}/X\geq1/2)=?$

Tags: self-study, distributions

> **Let X and Y are two independent uniformly distributed random variable on [0,1].The value of $P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{3}/X\geq1/2)=?$**

My try

$P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{3}/X\geq1/2)=\frac{P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{3},X\geq1/2)}{P(X\geq1/2)}$

Here I solved the denominator part that is $P(X\geq1/2)$,But the numerator part $P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{3},X\geq1/2)$ I am not getting any idea how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** See the following image. The area of the shaded parts is your answer:

[image]

$$P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{3},X\geq1/2) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\times (\frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{2})\times (1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\times((\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(1-\frac{1}{3}))\times(1-\frac{1}{2})\right)=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: why did you calculated the area of a random variable for finding probability its should be Probability density function axis but in your case horizontal axis is X varibale and vertical axis is Y variable..plz clarify

Comment: @Rohit it comes from the definition of the probability. Total state space is a unit square, and the probability space on the plane is the area of defined by the variables.

Comment: Sir can you please give me any reference to study because  I solved like that how you solved it but i was confused becasue It was the random  variable X  and Y not the PDF.because suppose i need to calculate P(X>1) then i need to calculate the area of pdf of X.not the area of variable

Comment: @Rohit Ok. your statement in general could be correct, but you've mentioned the distribution is uniform. Hence, this answer is what you want.

Comment: sir,if you can suggest me any book that i can read theory about this it will be helpful.

Comment: @Rohit each textbook on "introduction to probability" could be helpful.